# UndefinedMethodException: Attempted to call method "closeOutputBuffers" on class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response"

Tags: symfony, doctrine, output-buffering

I'm getting the following exception but I don't know where it came from:

> UndefinedMethodException: Attempted to call method
>   "closeOutputBuffers" on class
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" in
>   xx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Fragment/InlineFragmentRenderer.php
>   line 96.

Comment: You need to provide more information, otherwise we can't help you. **Where** is this exception thrown ? What are you trying to do? ... Show us some code :)

Comment: Glad to hear - then please delete the question ... or ... if you have the time and are willing to give something back to the community ...  provide the solution that worked for you as an answer :)

Comment: How did you solve it ? I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: I don't remember pretty much , but I think the problem is where you are trying to use getDoctrine() two times  with the same variable name $em in the same controller , I hope that can help .

Answer (score 0):

in my case this problem occurred because the result of the database contained invalid characters.

I solved this way

```
{{ name|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'iso-8859-1') }}
```